# Did J. R. R. Tolkien actually use to say that "Middle-earth was really the ancient history of the real planet Earth"?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, j-r-r-tolkien

> There was the also the fact that Tolkien, in later years, apparently gave up the conceit that Middle-earth was really the ancient history of the real planet Earth.

This was said in a comment/answer on SE. I had never heard of this before. Is it true? Did he mean that Silmarillion is literally the Bible of this world? Or did he just mean that in this fictional fantasy world/dimension, it is referring to our planet?

Comment: I'm not sure what in the Silmarillion lends itself to the bible as opposed to a history book or a book of lore

Comment: Tolkien's novels take place in a pre-Biblical period of Earth, I always thought, the same way that Howard's Hyborian Age was a pre-Biblical period before some great cataclysm wiped out much of Mankind and everything the preceded it and things just started over.